# Broadcast a wifi signal, have devices treat it like a hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I have a "Novatel Wireless™ MiFi® 7000".
I have it hooked with a canadian BELL sim card.

The problem, is that for devices connecting to it, it appears to be a regular wifi connection.

That means, a connected iPhone will download iOS updates, or a laptop will grab windows updates. This can burn a few GB per update. Valuable data to the plan and spikes in cost.

**Is it possible, to change the way the mifi 7000 broadcasts the signal**? I would think the solution would be to make it look like a smartphone hotspot connection. Because, for example when you connect to your friends hotspot, you can't update your phone or do other data-intense operations.

Comment: We have a classic issue here: The X/Y problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378 There's no way to change how your Novatel transmits and receives WiFi, because your devices would not be able to connect. Nor is there a way to change how it transmits and receives to Bell, for then Bell would ignore it. If we rephrase the issue to "How do I keep all my devices from using up my bandwidth", would that be suitable? If so, please click [edit] and revise your question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Check whether your devices have a "metered" setting for the Wi-Fi network. I know for a fact that modern Android devices have this as do Windows machines. This will tell the devices to limit their data usage on that network. This is a problem that should be solved on your connecting devices, not your "MiFi" device. In most cases this is a simple "check box" that is clickable when connecting to the Wi-Fi network.

Comment: @K7AAY I'm curious how iPhones do it. What makes the iPhone (and maybe android?) hotspot so special? We tried doing meter connections but iPhones have no special rules like that.

Comment: Not well informed regarding Apple, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented through firewall rules and device settings.

- For Windows devices, rather than try to change the Novatel Wireless MiFi 7000 connection, it is easier to set the [connection as *metered*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-metered-connection-in-windows-10) [i.e., costly] on each device. Windows will ask if you wish to download the update rather than barge ahead. Set the connection as metered on the device through *WiFi Settings*, by the CMD prompt, or using the simple Registry script below (be careful with Registry changes, and note that you may need to take ownership of the key to make this change, which also includes Ethernet wired connection and a reminder to the user. Change the values to "1" to set the connection to unmetered.

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost]

"3G"=dword:00000002

"4G"=dword:00000002

"Default"=dword:00000002

"Ethernet"=dword:00000002

"WiFi"=dword:00000002

"Values"="1=non-metered, 2= metered"`

- The iPhone, however, has no way to set a connection as metered. You need a firewall rule at the device or hotspot to [block the Apple update server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353046/stop-ios-auto-downloading-updates). (BTW, that would be difficult to implement for Windows, since multiple servers are used and in some cases Windows bypasses its firewall rules.)

[Some other changes on the iPhone can help save monthly bandwidth](https://www.getorchard.com/blog/wifi-hotspots-data-tips/):

- Set App Update off.
- Turn background App Refresh off.
- Set Photo Synch off.
- [Turning off iOS updates does **not** help](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-on-iphone-for-ios-12/): "for most devices, iOS still downloads any new updates in the background–it just doesn’t install those updates."

Comment: This isn't ideal for our use case. Many of these devices are peoples personal devices. We cannot police and control them setting our wifi as a metered connection. We want don't want to hold the wifi password so closely in our pockets that no one is allowed to use it. But we also want to prevent unnecessary usage, from our testing and numbers we would be at a much more manageable level, with just disabling these big updates.